# Characterization of special curves to be planar

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves, geodesic

I'm tryig to prove the following question. Let $M$ be a surface and $\alpha$ be a unit speed curve in M.

(1) $\alpha$ is both principal and geodesic iff it lies in a plane everywhere orthogonal to $M$ along $\alpha$.

(2) $\alpha$ is both principal asymptotic iff it lies in a plane everywhere tangent to $M$ along $\alpha$.

My thoughts: I know that if U is a unit normal vector field on M then $\alpha$ is principal implies that $\alpha'$ is collinear to U'. $\alpha$ is geodesic implies $\alpha''$ is normal to $M$. $\alpha$ is asymptotic implies $\alpha''$ is tangent to M. How do I use this information to say that $\alpha$ lies in a certain plane?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINTS**:

(1) If $\alpha$ is geodesic, as you've said, $\alpha''$ is parallel to $U$. So what is the derivative of $U\times\alpha'$?

(2) If $\alpha$ is principal, then $U' = k\alpha'$ for some function $k$ along $\alpha$; if $\alpha$ is an asymptotic curve, what is $k$?

Comment: 1. I could prove that since $\alpha$ is unit speed, its velocity is orthogonal to its acceleration. That tells me that U and $\alpha'$ are orthogonal and so the cross product is 0. Hence its derivative is 0. I'm failing to understand why this would tell us that $\alpha$ is planar.                                                                       2. I think $k$ should be 0, since $\alpha$ is asymptotic. So that gives us that $U'$ is 0. I again fail to understand how this implies $\alpha$ is planar. Also, Thanks a lot Dr. Shifrin. Your hints have been very useful to my understanding.

Comment: No, you're confusing the geometry of cross product and dot product. $U\times\alpha'$ is a most definitely a nonzero *vector*. (The cross product is $\vec 0$ if and only if the vectors are *parallel*.) If $U=U_0$ is constant along $\alpha$, then isn't $\alpha$ contained in a plane with normal vector $U_0$?

Comment: Ohh yes, of course. I see it now. Thanks a lot.